# Making a protocol agnostic jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, https, widget

We have a widget that is embedded in various website. We would like the widget to make an ajax call to our server according to the protocol (http or https) of the website in which we are embedded.
Is there a common practice to do that?

Using a protocol agnostic url (see below) doesn't work:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '//cdn.example.com/serviceName',
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn´t this work?

```
var myUrl = (window.location.protocol + '//cdn.example.com/serviceName');

$.ajax({
    url : myUrl,
    ...
});
```

Comment: The question was how to make the protocol agnostic url format work. For instance, if you type //www.google.com in your browser it will look for file://. But if you were on a server // would use whatever protocol you're currently serving the file from.